# React-bootstrap tabs: DefaultActiveKey locks the change of color on selected tab

Tags: reactjs, tabs, react-bootstrap

I have a strange issue - I have three tabs with `react-bootstrap`, they all work as intended and render as the logic implies.

However, it will, indeed, initialize on tab `{1}`. However, if I pick another tab, it will correctly initialize and render it, but the "visual" graphics of chosen tab won't change: It will still be bold on the first tab, rather than the selected one.

Here's the snip where it's rendered. Did I do something wrong?

```
        <div>
            <Tab.Container id="tabs-with-dropdown" activeKey={store.key} onSelect={store.handleSelect} defaultActiveKey={1} >
                <div>
                    <NavigationBar store={store} />
                    <Tab.Content animation>
                        <Tab.Pane eventKey={1}>
                            <Panels />
                        </Tab.Pane>
                        <Tab.Pane unmountOnExit={true} eventKey={2}>
                            <Settings  />
                        </Tab.Pane>
                        <Tab.Pane unmountOnExit={true} eventKey={3}>
                            <Users />
                        </Tab.Pane>
                    </Tab.Content>
                </div>
            </Tab.Container>
        </div>
```

And the navbar component, where you can navigate the tabs return something like this:

```
<div className="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"
                     style={{background: "#264b6b">
                    <div className="container-fluid">
                        <div className="navbar-header">
                            <div>
                                <Nav bsStyle="tabs" className="tabmenu"
                                     style={{
                                         position: "absolute",
                                         marginLeft: "14%",
                                         color: "white",
                                         backgroundColor: "#264b6b",
                                         borderBottom: "none",
                                         fontVariant: "small-caps",
                                         fontFamily: "'Open Sans', sans-serif",
                                         fontWeight: "400"
                                     }}>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={1}>
                                        panels
                                    </NavItem>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={2}>
                                        settings
                                    </NavItem>
                                    <NavItem eventKey={3}>
                                        users
                                    </NavItem>
                                </Nav>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Tab `{1}` will be marked as "active" all the time by the styling which is strange; the others are mounted and rendered in the react components. Any obvious reasons for this? It was working until recently, and I attempted to restore old commits to find the issue, but nothing really changed in the code here itself.

If I `console.log` the `store.key` and `store.handleSelect` they correctly mark the active tab as either 1, 2 or 3 with no issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use controlled tabs, so the `defaultActiveKey = 1` is not needed because it's used only for the uncontrolled Tabs component. You should initialize your tab by setting your `store.key` to the tab you want instead.